# How to get a human readable Android OS version

Tags: android, internationalization

It's fairly simple and straight forward to get the current devices API level using:

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

and using that it's also fairly easy to get the version name as of `Build.VERSION_CODES`

```
public static String getDisplayOS() {
    Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        int fieldValue = -1;

        try {
            fieldValue = field.getInt(new Object());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (fieldValue == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            return fieldName;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The problem is this gives values such as:

```
JELLY_BEAN_MR1
HONEYCOMB_MR2
```

Now, I could just manually add a list of OS version strings myself - which would be fine but once we get past API 22, I would have to update the product simply to add in some extra strings.

My brain tells me there must be an internal field which displays this value *somewhere* in the OS but I'm finding it decidedly difficult to find where this is.

Any help would be useful

Comment: ... use a switch case? Like: `switch(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT){case 1:return "First Android Version ever!";break;}`

Comment: Over what data set? I'm looking for the data set which includes human readable values which should be available somewhere on the device.

Comment: I don't think there is such a table anywhere (apart the one which returns "JELLY_BEAN_MR1"). Therefore, you get `MR1` and such. By the way, you could simply replace `"_"` with `" "` and `"MR"` with `"Maintenance Release "`. So, you'd get `"JELLY BEAN Maintenance Release 1"`. Even better, if you **proper-case** the strings (first char of every word uppercase, the rest lowercase), so to finally get `"Jelly Bean Maintenance Release 1"`. I can't think of anything simpler and nicer.

Comment: Yeah, that has always been my fallback position (I'll post as an answer now) but I don't want to have to resort to string manipulation which relies on Google keeping their naming convention (which, granted, is pretty likely at this stage)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack so I don't really want to use it. It does however manage to use regexing to pull out some pretty reasonable display values.

```
public static String[] getDisplayOS() {
    Field[] fields = Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        int fieldValue = -1;

        try {
            fieldValue = field.getInt(new Object());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (fieldValue == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {          
            fieldName = fieldName.replaceAll("_", " ");
            String firstLetter = fieldName.substring(0, 1);
            fieldName = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(1).toLowerCase();

             Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" [a-z]");
             Matcher m = p.matcher(fieldName);
             while (m.find()) {
                 int index = m.start();
                 fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, index) + fieldName.substring(index, index+2).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(index+2);
             }

             Pattern mrPattern = Pattern.compile(" (Mr\\d)");
             Matcher mrMatcher = mrPattern.matcher(fieldName);
             if (mrMatcher.find()) {
                 fieldName = fieldName.replaceAll(" Mr\\d", "");                 
                 return new String[] { fieldName, mrMatcher.group(1).toUpperCase() };
             }
             return new String[] { fieldName, null };
        }
    }
    return new String[] { null, null };
}
```